# "TypeError: expected a character buffer object" for loop and while loop function

Tags: python

I have written some code which takes a sample of 100 numbers and randomly samples them to increase the list of numbers, then cuts them back down to 100 at random.

I am counting the number of iterations through the loop it takes for all the numbers in the list to be the same number.

```
output = open("results.txt", 'w')
for i in range(100):
    population = range(0, 100)

    TTF = 0

    while len(set(population)) != 1:
        scalingfactor = np.random.poisson(5, 100)
        sample = np.repeat(population, scalingfactor)
        decrease-to-ten = np.random.choice(sample, 100)
        population = decrease-to-ten
        results += 1    
    output.write(str(results))
```

I am trying to output the numbers to a text file as a list, but I can't manage it.

```
output.write(str(results))
```

This gives me all the numbers together as one long string of numbers.

```
output.write(TTF)
```

gives me this error:

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way or another, you can only write character buffers to python File objects.  And python won't include newlines by default when you write to a file, you have to include those yourselves.

I'll also recommend using a context manager for your File object.

See this code:

```
with open("results.txt", 'w') as output:
    for i in range(100):
        population = range(0, 100)

        # TTF = 0  # Nothing is done with this number. Why is it here?

        while len(set(population)) != 1:
            scalingfactor = np.random.poisson(5, 100)
            sample = np.repeat(population, scalingfactor)
            decrease-to-ten = np.random.choice(sample, 100)
            population = decrease-to-ten
            results += 1    
        output.write(f"{results}\n")  # Assuming you're using Python >= 3.6
```

If you're on an older version of Python that doesn't support f-string, replace `f"{results}\n"` with `"{0}\n".format(results)`

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 so thanks for the clarification